# parallax effect not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have 2 "banner/hero" section on my home page, I'm trying to re use the "parallax" class on both banners. The issue is that it works perfectly on the first one, but when I add the parallax class to the second hero, the section completely disappears from the screen and the weird things is that this only happens when I set the background-repeat to no-repeat in the second hero section. Here's the code;

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.parallax').css('background-position', 'center ' +(wScroll)+'px')
  })

});
```

```css
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(205, 169, 157, 0.7), rgba(205, 169, 157, 0.7)), url(../img/home-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
}

.hero-secondary {
  height: 90vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(205, 169, 157, 0.7), rgba(205, 169, 157, 0.7)), url(../img/home-5.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: $color-white;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero parallax">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <h1 class="heading-primary">SS — 18</h1>
      <a href="#" class="button">Shop now</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <section class="hero-secondary parallax">
      <div class="hero-content">
        <h1 class="heading-primary">fw — 18</h1>
        <a href="#" class="button">Shop now</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I set background-repeat to repeat in the hero-secondary it works, but I need the image to no repeat itself. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: can you make the code working ? use good image path, include jquery, etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean? Everything is working fine the issue is when I set background-repeat: no repeat; in the hero-secondary class, as soon as I do that the section disappears from the webpage, if I dont set the background-repeat property it works but I need the image to no repeat.

Comment: I mean in the snippet here, click "run" and see ... there is many issues and we cannot run your code to see what is happening, so you need to make your code working in order to be able to reproduce the issues you are facing

Comment: Include JQuery in the snippet, and then we can see what you are attempting.

Comment: Ok I added Jquery to the snippet @TemaniAfif

Comment: we also need the image

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I fixed my issue, I had to edit the Jquery code to the following;

`$(window).scroll(function() {
    var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.parallax').css('background-position', 'center ' +(wScroll*0.30)+'px')
  })`

And remove the background-repeat property in the hero-secondary class. I still don't know why the section disappears if I set up the background-repeat: no-repeat. If any body can tell me why this happens I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.